# Is there a way to change controller name without changing controller file name?

Tags: asp.net, swagger

[image]

I wanna change ToDO to ApplicationApi. Is there a way to change it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add codes below at startup:

```
options.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));

options.TagActionsBy(api => new[] { api.GroupName });
```

Add codes below at each controller:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "YourDesireControllerName")]
```

Comment: will this work for changing the controller name for swagger documentation?